# Set multiple variables .onload to the same value

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
window.onload = function(){ 
  var rows = document.querySelector('.rows');
  var columns = document.querySelector('.columns');
  rows.onpaste = function(){return false;}
  columns.onpaste = function(){return false;} 
  rows.ondrop = function(){return false;}
  columns.ondrop = function(){return false;} 
}
```

is there any way that I can set all .ondrop and .onpaste to the same function in one line of code?

Comment: `rows.onpaste = columns.onpaste = rows.ondrop = columns.ondrop = function(){return false;} `?

Comment: If you want to select all elements with class `.rows` you need to use `document.querySeletorAll` not `document.querySelector`

Comment: i just have one element with class `.rows` and `.columns`, but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a simple way (although I don't think it's the nicest) would be something like this:

```
window.onload = function(){ 
  var rows = document.querySelector('.rows');
  var columns = document.querySelector('.columns');
  columns.ondrop = rows.ondrop = columns.onpaste = rows.onpaste = function(){return false;} 
}
```

Comment: which way do you think would be the nicest?

Comment: It depends on what you're doing, of course. But I like naming functions with a clear intention: `function disableEvent() { ... }`. In your case, it's a small script that you might be happy with the readability and lengthy line. Depending on how it grows, there are other abstractions that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one line like this

```
rows.ondrop = columns.ondrop = function(){return false;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use arrow function you can do it like this

```
var rows = document.querySelector('.rows');
var columns = document.querySelector('.columns');

rows.ondrop = columns.ondrop = () => false
rows.onpaste = columns.onpaste = () => false
```